# Android Studio Profiler Network is not showing Receiving Sending lines but shows Connections and details

Tags: android, networking, connection, profiler

Android Studio Profiler Network is not showing Receiving Sending lines but shows Connections and details.

I reinstalled Android studio check the settings but cannot find a solution.

[image]

Comment: I have had the same issue. I switched my avd api level from 30 to 28 and everything fine right now.

Comment: I have had the same issue on avd api30 i didnt switch api